# Error as I try to export the tf.estimator.DNNClassifier model. How could I save this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-estimator

I have created my estimator as :

```
estimator = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
   hidden_units=[500, 100],
   feature_columns=[embedded_text_feature_column],
   n_classes=2,
   optimizer=tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=0.003))
```

and run training as:

```
estimator.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps = 2)
```

After these two steps, I want to save my model/estimator. I tried the following:

```
# NOT SURE IF THE FOLLOWING FUNCTION IS CORRECT
def serving_input_receiver_fn():
  """Build the serving inputs."""
  # The outer dimension (None) allows us to batch up inputs for
  # efficiency. However, it also means that if we want a prediction
  # for a single instance, we'll need to wrap it in an outer list.

  inputs = {"x": tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 4], dtype=tf.float32)}
  return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(inputs, inputs)

export_dir = classifier.export_savedmodel(
  export_dir_base="/home/suhail/tensorflow-stubs/",
  serving_input_receiver_fn=serving_input_receiver_fn)
```

But this throws an error saying:`Feature sentence if not in features dictionary`. I trained the model [as given in doc at text_classification_with_tf_hub](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text_classification_with_tf_hub)

What is it that I am doing wrong?